# Laravel - can't get model after deleting related model records

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have a function `postShippingmethods` in which I delete, update or create new shipping methods depending what the user specified in the form. It works like it should , except that if any methods are deleted, I get empty result when trying to retrieve the user model with the updated methods.

To delete methods, I first get the user:

```php
$user = \App\User::where('id',$id)->with(['shipping_profiles' => function($query) {
                    $query->where('default', 1);
                }, 'shipping_profiles.methods' ])->first();
```

I compare the stored methods to the ones in the request; if any are missing , they should be deleted.

This code does the deletion:

```php
 foreach($non_included_ids as $id){
                    $method = \App\ShippingMethod::find($id);
                    $method->suppliers()->detach();
                    $method->delete();
                }
```

Then I get the user once again, to get the **updated** data:

```php
$user = \App\User::where('id',$id)->with(['shipping_profiles' => function($query) {
                    $query->where('default', 1);
                }, 'shipping_profiles.methods' ])->first();
```

^^ this works well if nothing was deleted, but for some reason **if something was deleted**, the above code will return nothing. And when I try to use the `$user` to retrieve data I of course get `"Trying to get property of non object"`.

So can anyone explain why this happen and what I should do to get the user with the updated data?

Comment: I would guess that `foreach($non_included_ids as $id){` changes the value of `$id`. Then `\App\User::where('id',$id)` fetches the wrong user.

Comment: That was it! Never thought of it.. big thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a different variable name in the loop:

```
foreach($non_included_ids as $non_included_id){
```

Otherwise, the loop changes the value of `$id` and `\App\User::where('id',$id)` fetches the wrong user.